# openlayers - wms - map not loading - what Bounds/Extent/Scale to use?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms

I simply want a map on a webpage where I can zoomin and zoomout and navigate around.
I'm working on this for 4 days now, and can't get it to work:

I want to display the map using a WMS-service here in Austria with Openlayers. Here's the getCap XML:

```
http://gis.lebensministerium.at/wmsgw/?key=6ae2a41178c77ccee1db7248c9f92b04&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS
```

so this is my openlayers code:

```
function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
        controls : map_controls
            });
    wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("GIS", "http://gis.lebensministerium.at/wmsgw/", {
        layers : 'Orthophoto,Luftbild_MR,Luftbild_1m,Luftbild_8m,Satellitenbild_30m',
        key : '6ae2a41178c77ccee1db7248c9f92b04'
            }, {
                projection : new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:31287'),
                maxExtent : new OpenLayers.Bounds(110000, 250000, 690000, 590000)
            });
    map.addLayer(wms);
    if(!map.getCenter()) {
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }}
```

and here's the link to take a look at the actual page: [myMapSite](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2418858/index2.html)

but it should look something like this (made it with an desktop app): [Link_to_Picture](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2418858/gis.lebensministerium.at.png)

(I think the small rectangles are due to the free service and to not use it commercially)

So basically I want to see the whole map and then zoom in.

Since the only way to see a map (although the zoom-factor is way off) was to set the maxExtend with the boundingBox values from the getCapabilities-xml file, I'm assuming that my Bounds/Extent/Scale is wrong?

But what values should I use? or is there another problem?

I'm really desperate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the *property* `maxResolution` on the `map` object:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
    controls : map_controls,
    maxResolution: 1000
});
```

Comment: it didn't work with maxResolution: 1000 but it did work with maxResolution: 'auto'!!!!! I'm sooooo happy right now! THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Well it did work with `maxResolution: 1000` when I injected the value using *FireBug* on your site - but if `maxResolution: 'auto'` works for you, then great ;)